# Mysql multiple connection tree/neural structure, get all connections recursive

Tags: mysql, recursion

I am trying to figure out how to get the connections of a structure like:

```
id  connection    
...
74          0 
74         76
74         83 
76         79
79         85
85          0
...
```

What I would need is to get all connections of 74, so 76, 83 but also all connections of the 76 and 83 recursively.

I managed to do this via backend but its performance will be affected in time.

How can I write this in mysql in order to get something like?
[76, 79, 85, 83]
I am using mysql 8

[sql fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p9HBkhP2vaXrpDButYzykS/2)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `connections` (
  `_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `connection_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `connections` (`id`, `connection_id`) VALUES
  (74, 0),
  (74, 76),
  (74, 83),
  (76, 79),
  (79, 85),
  (85, 0);
```

I am using Mariadb 10.1.48, and the desired output:

```
id 
76  
83  
79 
85
```

**EDIT**
I tried writing it like:

```
SELECT T2.* 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @r AS id_, 
        (SELECT @r := connection_id FROM connections WHERE id = id_) AS connection_id, 
        @l := @l + 1 AS lvl 
    FROM 
        (SELECT @r := 74, @l := 0) vars, 
        connections h 
    WHERE @r <> 0) T1 
JOIN connections T2 
ON T1.id_ = T2.id 
ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC
```

But I get only the first level of the connections:

Also tried as suggested with CTE but don't know how to get just the connections of one of the items... ex.: 74

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id_, connection_id_) AS
(
  SELECT id, connection_id FROM connections WHERE id = (SELECT 
MIN(id) FROM connections)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    c.connection_id_, t.connection_id
  FROM
    cte c
  JOIN connections t
  ON c.connection_id_ = t.id
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

Comment: Provide: precise MySQL version, complete CREATE TABLE script, sample data as INSERT INTO script, desired output for this data. Scripts as code-formatted text, output - table-formatted.

Comment: Thank you! Just added a small fiddle for the case I have.

Comment: See the basic structure here.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301903/recursive-query-on-a-self-referential-table-where-each-node-has-one-link-to-its

Comment: I tried using it, see updated fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p9HBkhP2vaXrpDButYzykS/1 but I am not able to constrain it jut to the connections of one specific id, ex 74

Comment: *Provide: **precise MySQL version**, ... **desired output for this data**, ...*

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=f124b9669f136d6c4fb83dc7d2a4c748

Comment: @SOS it works, thank you. What should I do to prevent circular references, as if the data does contain circular references it fails due to @@cte_max_recursion_depth

Comment: @sonaRapanj - If at all possible, it should be detected before insertion into the database. Also, have a look at this thread for detecting circular references https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71592214/recursive-parent-child-problem-in-mariadb#comment126531725_71592214